# Adding Friends on Different Platforms to Real Racing 3

Tags: real-racing-3

I'm using the Android version (Jelly Bean/Nexus 7) of EA Real Racing 3, and my friend is on the iOS version.  He keeps sending me invites, and when I accept them from facebook, it keeps sending me to the google play store.  How do I accept his request?  Is there no link between platforms maybe, or what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Try sending him an invite as well so he can respond, also make sure your game is signed on through facebook